# Simple switch to instanced draws causes consistent, but incorrect, results

Tags: directx11, instancing

I have dumbed the following code down to "stupid simple" for DirectX and still cannot get any cooperation:

```
g_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, g_renderTargetWorld->ColorRenderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), g_depthStencilView.Get());
g_d3dContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(g_States->DepthNone(), 0);
g_d3dContext->OMSetBlendState(g_States->AlphaBlend(), NULL, 0xffffffff);
g_d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 2, m_segments->GetLineVertexBuffers(), s_strides, s_offsets);
g_d3dContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_segments->GetLineIndexBuffer(), DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
g_d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(s_IL_Polyline.Get());
g_d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINELIST_ADJ);
g_d3dContext->VSSetShader(g_World_Polyline_VS_Segment.Get(), NULL, 0);
g_d3dContext->GSSetShader(g_World_Polyline_GS_Segment.Get(), NULL, 0);
g_d3dContext->PSSetShader(g_World_Polyline_PS_Segment.Get(), NULL, 0);
g_d3dContext->RSSetState(g_States->CullNone());
//g_d3dContext->DrawIndexed(4 * m_segments->LineCount, 0, 0);
g_d3dContext->DrawIndexedInstanced(4, m_segments->LineCount, 0, 0, 0);
g_d3dContext->GSSetShader(nullptr, NULL, 0);
```

-The DrawIndexed call draws all segments
-The DrawIndexedInstanced call draws only the first segment

Creating a second instance of this class, DrawIndexedInstanced draws only the first segment of each compound line. Although it is correctly created, filled, and set, I am not even using the per-instance data yet. Manually manipulating the StartIndexOffset parameter causes different, only-one, line segments to be drawn.

PIX is worthless, as usual, but, at least, allowed me to inspect the buffer contents. All of the data is correct and in-place but I cannot get the "gosh-darn" thing to work. After 18 hours of searching and getting nowhere, I'm livid, giving up, and going to bed.

Please help me explain why (4*2) != 4[0:1]

**Edit**:
This, stupidly, works:

```
for (char i = 0; i < m_segments->LineCount; i++)
{
    g_d3dContext->DrawIndexedInstanced(4, 1, i * 4, 0, i * 4);
}
```

So, now: (4[0] + 4[1]) == (4*2) != 4[0:1]

Verifying, again, that the data is all where it needs to be.. Stumped. It's got to be something so obvious, that it's not. I feel like I'm already over-kill on setting every possible state parameter there is and if I comment any one line, it would switch from *doesn't* work to *shouldn't* work and I can't debug it.

Comment: Can you modify your title to be more descriptive of the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a newbie error. I RTFM, but didn't pay close enough attention and, apparently, hadn't used this draw call in this way before.

Specifically:

This draws 8 consecutively-indexed vertices starting at index 0:

```
g_d3dContext->DrawIndexed(4 * m_segments->LineCount, 0, 0);
```

This draws the same 4 consecutively-indexed vertices, starting at index 0, LineCount times:

```
g_d3dContext->DrawIndexedInstanced(4, m_segments->LineCount, 0, 0, 0);
```

Since my per-instance data doesn't offer a way to translate the pattern of vertices into place, it's drawing the same segment over and over.

To fix this, I will stuff the coordinates from the 4 separate vertices into a single vertex; each vertex will represent an entire segment.